# How to save an external page using JavaScript (in Chrome extension)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, save, html

I can save the current page (or another tab's page) in a chrome extension like:

```
chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML(object details, function callback)
```

Can I save somehow a specified URL's page with javascript (not PHP)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is no, the [chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageCapture.html) requires you to pass in the ID of the tab you wish to capture. [MHTML](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2557) files embed all the resources (e.g. images, css, javascript etc) associated with a HTML document into a single file.

Another method you could use to capture the HTML is by using a [xmlhttprequest](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp). Although you'd need to make individual calls to capture all the associated resources.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var responseHtml = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.website.com/target.html", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```